# Modify an element in Map

Tags: list, dictionary, ocaml, mutable

I have defined some types as follows:

```
module SMap = Map.Make(String)

type s = 
  { t: int
    fa: int list } 

type t = s SMap.t
```

I would like to write a function `modify` to add `100` to the list `fa` for the element corresponding to `key`. The following code works:

```
let modify (key: String) (x: t) =
  let a = SMap.find key x in
  SMap.add key { a with fa = a.fa @ [100] } (SMap.remove key x)
```

However, removing and adding an element looks redundant for me... Could any tell me if there is a better way to directly modify it?

Comment: You don't need to remove it, if you add an existing key, it will be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just add it.

A map can contain a key only once, so if you add another mapping with this key, it will remove the previous one.

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.Make.html#VALadd